# how to check array of value in hibernate table column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays, hibernate

I have a partdetails table, in this partdetails I have preloaded data. Every time I bill the customer I will get data from partdetails table, if I don't have any data in my table it means I typed all the details and bill the customer so newly added part details information need to be added in that partdetails table. This is what I'm trying to do.

I'm using hibernate...
for example, my data look like this

```
part[0]="abc123" assume (already in table)
part[1]="def123" assume (already not in table)
part[2]="ghi123" assume (already in table)
part[3]="jkl123" assume (already not in table)

select valueflagarray from partsdetails where part
```

I need a valueflagarray like

```
valueflagarray[0]=true
valueflagarray[1]=false
valueflagarray[2]=true
valueflagarray[3]=false
```

using this array i ll insert information about tat part if valueflagarray=flase..

the above problem I can use a **for loop** for a select statement. But I need a clean solution because I have millions of records.

```
array A;
    for (int i=0;i<part.length;i++){
select * from partdetails where partnumber=part[i]
A[i]=resultset.length;
```

}
I will get a result like this but I don't want this solution.

```
A[0]=1;
A[1]=1;
A[2]=0;
A[3]=1;
```

..
Is there any inbuilt functionality in hibernate or something else but I need to reduce processing time.
Please Help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing the query in a for loop and reaching out to database for results again and again, you should execute a single query like this :

```
select * from partdetails where partnumber in (Arrays.stream(part).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Collect these results into a List from Resultset

Now, iterate over the array and check if that part exists in the results list. If not, add it to your valueflagarray.